# My light switch is stuck in on position and blew all the lights of the house off!

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

My kitchen has a 2 gang light switch which one of the switches have been blowing all the lights in the house whenever turned on, I accidentally turned it on today and it is stuck in the on position so we have no lights! I can't reset the switch board as it keeps blowing due to the kitchen light switch staying on... Please help!

Comment: "one of the switches have been blowing all the lights in the house whenever turned on" - is this a new occurrence? Did it start happening spontaneously, or has someone been fiddling with the switches or wiring?

Comment: The switch has gone bad, obviously. Replace it, or hire someone to do it. Or, does this coincide with DIY work? You probably crossed some wires on the switch. In that case, get some help. You're not ready for DIY electrical.

Answer (score 4):

A faulty light switch can trip the breaker for the circuit that it's on.  It shouldn't be able to make your *whole house* go dark.  It sounds like you have something seriously wrong with your wiring.

Try shutting off power to the whole house.  While the power is off, remove the problematic switch and cap and label the wires that were connected to it.  Turn off the breaker to the switch's circuit, then try turning power to the rest of the house back on.  With the faulty device removed, you should be able to power the rest of the house leaving only this one circuit disabled.  Then, call an electrician to fix your much larger problem.

Comment: Absolutely. Whatever was done to the house before this started was not only wrong but dangerously wrong, as in risk not just of electrocution but of house fire. They are clearly not competent to fix it. You can't afford _not_ to have a pro resolve this.

Comment: I would be a bit more cautious with this answer.  If the lights are out due to a master trip or transformer fault protection then this kind of tinkering could overlook an unfused branch or an open neutral.

Comment: Prior to recent upgrade to the current UK standard of ground fault breaker per circuit, my house had a global ground fault breaker, so a ground fault in one appliance would trip the whole house. There isn't detail in the OP to necessarily imply something seriously wrong with the wiring; e.g. the difference between global and per-circuit ground fault breakers is a matter of convenience not safety.